# Why does read access for artifactory's rendered directory listing behaves inconsistently?

Tags: artifactory, subdirectory, artifacts

I want to give access to some artifacts in a publicly available generic repository. This is working fine. But there are also some artifacts which should only be available if you are logged in or have an account in our artifactory.
Of course, if you are not logged in you can not see links to access restricted artifacts. To solve this I added a readme file which contains the links to those restricted folders. Accessing those leads to a basic auth login field, as it should be.

But here comes the issue. I am now logged in with the browser (got token, cookie, whatever), navigate back to root view, and still can not see the links. When accessing the links from my readme I do not have to log in again, obviously. And after reloading the page some times, I can see those links.

What did I do wrong here? Is there a way to give public (anonymous) access to folders, but not to artifacts?

Thanks,
Thomas.

Comment: Have you tried using the Include/Exclude patterns on the permission target?

Comment: ah damn, thank you, why I did i not thought about this.
I now include * and exclude */** for anonymous, which does the job.